# Creating a data frame from two vectors using cbind

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following R code.

```
> x = cbind(c(10, 20), c("[]", "[]"), c("[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]"))
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]     
[1,] "10" "[]" "[[1,2]]"
[2,] "20" "[]" "[[1,3]]"
```

Similarly

```
> x = rbind(c(10, "[]", "[[1,2]]"), c(20, "[]", "[[1,3]]"))
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]     
[1,] "10" "[]" "[[1,2]]"
[2,] "20" "[]" "[[1,3]]"
```

Now, I don't want the integers `10` and `20` to be converted to strings.
How can I perform this operation without any such conversion? I would of
course also like to know why this conversion happens. I looked at
the `cbind` help and also tried Googling, but had no luck finding a
solution. I also believe that in some cases. R converts strings to
factors, and I don't want that to happen either, though it doesn't seem
to be happening here.

Comment: The problem is not with `cbind`, but with `c`. That is the function you need to understand better.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Vectors and matrices can only be of a single type and `cbind` and `rbind` on vectors will give matrices. In these cases, the numeric values will be promoted to character values since that type will hold all the values.

(Note that in your `rbind` example, the promotion happens within the `c` call:

```
> c(10, "[]", "[[1,2]]")
[1] "10"      "[]"      "[[1,2]]"
```

If you want a rectangular structure where the columns can be different types, you want a `data.frame`. Any of the following should get you what you want:

```
> x = data.frame(v1=c(10, 20), v2=c("[]", "[]"), v3=c("[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]"))
> x
  v1 v2      v3
1 10 [] [[1,2]]
2 20 [] [[1,3]]
> str(x)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ v1: num  10 20
 $ v2: Factor w/ 1 level "[]": 1 1
 $ v3: Factor w/ 2 levels "[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]": 1 2
```

or (using specifically the `data.frame` version of `cbind`)

```
> x = cbind.data.frame(c(10, 20), c("[]", "[]"), c("[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]"))
> x
  c(10, 20) c("[]", "[]") c("[[1,2]]", "[[1,3]]")
1        10            []                 [[1,2]]
2        20            []                 [[1,3]]
> str(x)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ c(10, 20)              : num  10 20
 $ c("[]", "[]")          : Factor w/ 1 level "[]": 1 1
 $ c("[[1,2]]", "[[1,3]]"): Factor w/ 2 levels "[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]": 1 2
```

or (using `cbind`, but making the first a `data.frame` so that it combines as data.frames do):

```
> x = cbind(data.frame(c(10, 20)), c("[]", "[]"), c("[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]"))
> x
  c.10..20. c("[]", "[]") c("[[1,2]]", "[[1,3]]")
1        10            []                 [[1,2]]
2        20            []                 [[1,3]]
> str(x)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ c.10..20.              : num  10 20
 $ c("[]", "[]")          : Factor w/ 1 level "[]": 1 1
 $ c("[[1,2]]", "[[1,3]]"): Factor w/ 2 levels "[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]": 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I don't think I need the properties of Factors here, and my recollection is that they can cause problems. Is there some way of creating a data frame with string values instead?

Comment: Add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the `data.frame` calls. If the calls are implicit (as in the last example), then you have to make them explicit: `data.frame(c("[]", "[]"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Comment: There is a global option `stringsAsFactors` as well which controls this. I leave it as the shipped default and change it on an as-needed basis for reproducibility.

Comment: I get `$ c("[]", "[]") : chr "[]" "[]"` instead of `$ c("[]", "[]") : Factor w/ 1 level "[]": 1 1.` I'm using R 1.15.1. Any idea why the difference?

Comment: What do you get for `getOption("stringsAsFactors")`?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot I set `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` in .Rprofile. Maybe that wasn't such a good idea.

Answer (score 16):

Using `data.frame` instead of `cbind` should be helpful

```
x <- data.frame(col1=c(10, 20), col2=c("[]", "[]"), col3=c("[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]"))
x
  col1 col2    col3
1   10   [] [[1,2]]
2   20   [] [[1,3]]

sapply(x, class) # looking into x to see the class of each element
     col1      col2      col3 
"numeric"  "factor"  "factor"
```

As you can see elements from col1 are `numeric` as you wish.

`data.frame` can have variables of different `class`: `numeric`, `factor` and `character` but `matrix` doesn't, once you put a `character` element into a matrix all the other will become into this class no matter what clase they were before.

Comment: Thanks. Can I make the class of `col2` and `col3` into string?