# Convert list returned by sapply() to a data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sapply

I have a list returned by sapply()

```
$my.list <- sapply()  
$my.list  
"var1" "var2" "var3"  
 1.1    2.5    3.2
```

The ideal result is to transform **my.list** into a data frame **df**:

```
$df  
"var1"  1.1  
"var2"  2.5  
"var3"  3.2
```

I have tried to 'subset' each row of **my.list** as follows:

```
$p1 <- names(my.list)  
$p1  
   "var1" "var2" "var3"  
$p2 <- as.vector(my.list)
$p2 
   1.1 2.5 3.2
```

But then I had no further luck cbind/rbind-ing these row vectors into a data frame. Any thoughts/suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Edit: the ideal result will have $ dim(df) return: 3 2 -- ie 3 observations of 2 variables.

Comment: what are the two variables here? `varname` and `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you require.

```
my.list <- as.data.frame(sapply(trees,mean))
my.list <- cbind(my.list,rownames(my.list))
rownames(my.list) <- NULL
```

I'm sure there might be some other smart ways to do it !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `stack`.  Here I make up a named "list" (really a vector) as you might get from `sapply`.  Note this works even if your data is actually a list.

```
> my.list <- setNames(1:3, letters[1:3])
> my.list
a b c 
1 2 3
> stack(my.list)
  values ind
1      1   a
2      2   b
3      3   c
```

Comment: stack() looks useful except that it keeps "levels" of element "ind" of my.list as returned by sapply(). Let's say: ps <- stack(my.list). ps$values is good. But ps$ind returns levels in addition to values. This will cause problems in processing ps further.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% this is what you want, is this what you mean?

```
my.list <- sapply(letters[1:3], toupper)
data.frame(t(my.list))
```

(Next time please provide us with your input to make it easier to answer)

Comment: If df <- data.frame(t(my.list)) then dim(df) return: 1 3 -- 3 observations of 1 variable. This is not the desired outcome. The ideal outcome in my example is to have dim(df) return: 3 2 -- 3 observations of 2 variables. Shall edit the question?

Comment: It's actually one observation of 3 variables. Based on your input, that seemed to make sense - you had "var1" "var2" and "var3" , one value for each.  I'm not sure what you want the output to look like... please be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Binding **p1** and **p2** into **df** is similar to question #12787551

Here is the solution:
To remove the levels in p1 (factor)

```
$p1 <- as.numeric(names(my.list))
```

Then to construct **df**

```
$df <- cbind(data.frame(p1),p2)
```

The ideal result will then return:

```
$dim(df)
3 2
$df$p1
var1 var2 var3
```

Comment: to question: 12787551 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787551/creating-a-data-frame-from-two-vectors-using-cbind