# Convert any number of vectors into a dataframe whilst preserving data types and using vector names as column names in R

Tags: r

Is there a simple function (preferably user-written, or found in base R) that takes any number of vectors, and produces a dataframe whist retaining the vectors' data types, and using the vector variables' names as the column names?

#### An example

Inputs (vectors)

```
> var_a # character
[1] "a" "b" "c"

> var_b # numeric
[1] 1 3 4

> var_c # factor
[1] red   black black
Levels: black red
```

Desired output

```
  var_a var_b var_c
1     a     1   red
2     b     3 black
3     c     4 black
```

where the classes are

```
sapply(my_dataframe, class)

#      var_a       var_b       var_c 
#"character"   "numeric"    "factor"
```

#### Attempt 1 - Using `cbind`

Using `cbind` will produce a matrix (with a single data type) - so this method does not maintain the vectors' original data types (it changes all columns to character)

```r
first_method <- cbind(var_a, var_b, var_c)
```

#### Attempt 2 - Using `do.call` (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988483/combine-vectors-inside-of-a-list-to-create-a-dataframe-r))

In this case the data types are lost and so are the names of the vector variables

```
ls <- list(var_a, var_b, var_c)
second_method <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, ls))
second_method %>% sapply(class)
#       X1       X2       X3 
# "factor" "factor" "factor"
```

#### Attempt 3 - using `data.frame`

This method gets close (it retains the vector names as column names in the dataframe), but unfortunately it converts character data types into factors

```r
third_method <- data.frame(var_a, var_b, var_c)
third_method %>% sapply(class)
#    var_a     var_b     var_c 
# "factor" "numeric"  "factor"
```

#### Attempt 4 - Manually declaring each column of the dataframe, AND its name, AND its datatype

This returns the desired output, however, it is not eloquent, instead taking a ***lot*** of manual coding for large numbers of vectors, and is prone to user error because the user must specify the datatype manually for each column

```r
fourth_method <- data.frame("var_a"=as.character(var_a), "var_b"=as.numeric(var_b), "var_c"=as.factor(var_c), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fourth_method %>% sapply(class)

#      var_a       var_b       var_c 
#"character"   "numeric"    "factor"
```

Note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173557/how-to-transform-a-vector-into-data-frame-with-fixed-dimension), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787551/creating-a-data-frame-from-two-vectors-using-cbind), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662457/convert-list-of-vectors-to-data-frame) solution are unsuitable as they result in loss of data type

Also note: The vectors in this question are not named vectors as referred to in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816032/convert-named-character-vector-to-data-frame) question

At this point, I am running low on ideas and am unsure what to try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine with `data.frame`.  You just need to add the argument, `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

```
df = data.frame(var_a, var_b, var_c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sapply(df, class)
      var_a       var_b       var_c 
"character"   "numeric"    "factor"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tibble` to preserve the column types

```
library(tibble)
tibble(var_a, var_b, var_c)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  var_a var_b var_c
#  <chr> <dbl> <fct>
#1 a         1 red  
#2 b         3 black
#3 c         4 black
```

NOTE: `tibble` can be used with `tidyverse` operations, but if we really require `data.frame`, converting it to `data.frame` would still preserve the data types

```
tibble(var_a, var_b, var_c) %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    str
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ var_a: chr  "a" "b" "c"
# $ var_b: num  1 3 4
# $ var_c: Factor w/ 2 levels "black","red": 2 1 1
```